# How to compare two arrays in python with 1s for hits and 0s for non-hits?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to compare two numpy arrays with the same size together. I want the similar answer like Matlab:

```
  a = [ 1 2 3];
  b = [ 1 -2 3];
  c = a==b; % c = [1 0 1]
```

How can I do that in python? is there any function or I should do that with code?

Thanks :)

Comment: Since you mentioned Numpy, `np.array([1, 2, 3]) == np.array([1, -2, 3])` returns `np.array([True, False, True])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy already gives pretty much the same result that you are looking for:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([1, -2, 3])
>>> c = a == b
>>> c
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Without NumPy:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, -2, 3]
>>> [x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[True, False, True]
```

Or using `map` with `operator.eq`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.eq, a, b)
[True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 3):

Without numpy:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]     
>>> b = [1,-2,3]
>>> c = [a==b for a, b in zip(a,b)]
>>> c
[True, False, True]
```

Or casting to int as Joran indicated:

```
>>> c = [int(a==b) for a, b in zip(a,b)]
>>> c
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: may as well cast the bool to an int so it matches problem description but yeah +1

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it, without numpy:

```
c = []
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    if i==j:
        c.append(1)
    else:
        c.append(0)
```